# When DNS resolution is done in QtWebKit?

Tags: web, dns, webkit, ip-address, qtwebkit

I'm using QtWebkit and I want to monitor the request created in QtWebKit.

When the DNS name is resolved to IP address to make the request to Web Server?

Also Do QtWebKit maintaines(I guess YES) the cache of resolved IP address?

Answer (score 0):

- Reading comments in `DNSPrefetchHelper::lookedUp`([1](https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/v5.4.1/Source/WebCore/platform/network/qt/DNSQt.cpp#L58)), I assume in addition to normal DNS request cases (1) and (2), Qt also takes pre fetches DNS as in (3)

  1. normal DNS lookups made for page navigation requests
  2. during html parsing ( for internal JS/CSS/IMG like resource files)
  3. pre fetches DNS on actions like user mouse over an `href` ( anticipating a click and resulting navigation )
- Reading comments in a Qt function `DNSPrefetchHelper::lookedUp`([2](https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/v5.4.1/Source/WebCore/platform/network/qt/DNSQt.cpp#L50)), I assume Qt caches only a very small amount of DNS results. It relies mainly on OS to cache the DNS results. I also feel this is the best way to handle dns caches, even if you happen to implement one. The moment application tries to maintain dns caches, it will be confusing to make a performance decision between when to flush the dns cache vs accurate results.

  In the unlikely scenario of OS failing to cache dns results, Qt expects ISP to cache it.

> ```
> void lookedUp(const QHostInfo&)
> {
>     // we do not cache the result, we throw it away.
>     // we currently rely on the OS to cache the results. If it does not do that
>     // then at least the ISP nameserver did it.
>     // Since Qt 4.6.3, Qt also has a small DNS cache.
>     DNSResolveQueue::shared().decrementRequestCount();
> }
> ```

Related files are ([a](https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/v5.4.1/Source/WebCore/platform/network/DNSResolveQueue.h))([b](https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/v5.4.1/Source/WebCore/platform/network/DNSResolveQueue.cpp))([c](https://github.com/qtproject/qtwebkit/blob/24a674183c7b620b8a12734f8a4da3a601939238/Source/WebCore/platform/network/cf/DNSCFNet.cpp))